# Angular 2+ append class in directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular2-hostbinding

I have Angular 6.0.0 application. Need to dynamically append classes to html elements. Ideally, this should be implemented via directive.
Currently I have something like this and it works OK.

```
<div class="class1 prefix-{{variable}}"></div>
```

I want to make the prefix reusable and I am trying to reach the better result by using a directive:

html:

```
<div class="class1" [appendBusinessLogicClass]="variable"></div>
```

appendBusinessLogicClass.directive.ts:

```
export class AppendBusinessLogicClass {
readonly prefix = 'prefix';
  @HostBinding('class') class = ''; // this clears the html class1
  @Input('appendBusinessLogicClass') set appendBusinessLogicClass(variable: string) {
      this.class = this.prefix + '-' + variable;
   }
}
```

But the HostBinding CLEARS `class1` in the html code. But I'd like to APPEND `'prefix-rand'` to the class list.
Note, that we do not know `variable` at the compile time.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're actually doing now is binding to the class attribute, so basically the value will be `set` to `this.class`, which is completely fine. However, it turns out you're not actually getting the initial value from the 'class' attribute and this means no matter whatever you set `class` to be on your template, the value will always be overwritten. So basically Angular is taking over setting that `class` attribute.

So, what you have to do is get a reference of that value in the `class` attribute. In Angular you can actually consider any `html` attribute to be an input to your component/directive, the only thing you have to do is annotate it with an `@Input` decorator. Here we're saving the value of the  `class` attribute to `defaultClassList` and then using it to compute the new `class` attribute value, so your code could look like this:

```
export class AppendBusinessLogicClass {
    readonly prefix = 'prefix';

    @Input('class')
    defaultClassList;// `class` is a keyword so we're calling it defaultClassList instead

    @HostBinding('class')
    classList;// `class` is a keyword so we're calling it classList instead

    @Input('appendBusinessLogicClass') set appendBusinessLogicClass(variable: string) {
        this.classList = this.defaultClassList + " " + this.prefix + '-' + variable;
    }
}
```

So to sum up, you end up getting the attribute value defined in your template and including it in your bound `this.classList` whenever the value you pass to the directive is set.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!

Comment: Having playing a bit with your solution, found a bug, that the classList conflicts with [class.another-class] in html.

Can you advise something?

Comment: How does it collide? what ends up being the output? what happens if you use `ngClass` instead?

Comment: The directive prevents `another-class` to be applied when setting  [class.another-class] in the same html tag.

`[ngClass]` syntax does not let me generate dynamic classes like `prefix-{{variable}}`.

Comment: Ok, I'll explore some other alternatives as soon as I get some available time... perhaps using the `host` property on the `@Directive` decorator might help (I know it has a different behaviour than using @HostBinding). I'll let you know if anything shows up